# Обязательное поле для формы

Tags: javascript, php, html, html-select

Необходимо сделать обязательным выбор страны. Использовал в тэге select атрибут required - не помогло. Добавил required="true" аналогично не помогло. Спасибо.

Поле для формы:

```
 <div class="form-group row">
                    <div class="col-12">
                        <select class="form-control" name="country_id" required="true">
                            <option value="0">Страна</option>
                            <?php
                            $data = array('is_active' => 1);
                            $RESULT_COUNTRY = $DBH->prepare("SELECT * FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "country WHERE is_active = :is_active ");
                            $RESULT_COUNTRY->execute($data);
                            $RESULT_COUNTRY->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                            while ($row_country = $RESULT_COUNTRY->fetch()) { ?>
                                <option value="<?php echo $row_country['id'] ?>" <?php echo $row_country['id'] == $row['country_id'] ? 'selected' : ''; ?>><?php echo $row_country['name'] ?></option>
                            <?php } ?>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: Уже выполняем..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Потому что не заполненное значение это пустая строка, а не "0"

Поменяйте value на ""

```
<select class="form-control" name="country_id" required="required">
  <option value="">Страна</option>
```

Comment: Правильно, а также можно сократить до `<select class="form-control" name="country_id" required>` :)

Comment: @Mully Привычка писать well-formed XML